# index/match multiple criteria and repeat value n times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rows, repeat

I need help finishing off this formula. it needs to:

- Identify where the first `value` should go
- identify when there is a change in `value` within the same `location`. For example, Los Angeles has two separate `value`

This is what i have so far (assuming the en:

```
=IF(ROW()-1="","",IF(ROW()<=ROW($F$2)+INDEX($A$2:$D$7,MATCH($F$1,$A$2:$A$7),4)-1,INDEX($A$2:$D$7,MATCH($F$1,$A$2:$A$7),3),0))
```

assume that the Sample Data is in A1 to D7 and the Ideal Outcome starts in E1 and that you filled 0.12 in cell F2.

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Ideal Outcome:**
It should index/match the `location` and `start_time` and copy the `value` based on the `replicate` count as shown below.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions/approach

Comment: Use a two-dimensioned array VBA.

Comment: @jeeped im hoping to avoid VBA. Im running on a Mac computer and VBA is limiting on Macs, in my experience that is.

Comment: ... but arrays are not.

Comment: @Jeeped can you steer me to a starting point on that? i'd really appreciate. I dont have much experience with array VBA.

Comment: If you write some code and run into a problem then edit your question to include your own effort and I will attempt to help with that. If you don't want to try writing code then hire someone. SO is for professional programmers and programming enthusiasts; it is not Kindergarten for Excel VBA novices, there are plenty of other resources on the interweb for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that having 2 times "New York" in the second list is an error (as LA is not).

Having each city just one time there, a formula like the following will do (just change the ranges so it fits your real ranges):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G$1=$A$2:$A$7)*($F2>=$B$2:$B$7)*($F2<=($B$2:$B$7+"00:30"*$D$2:$D$7))*$C$2:$C$7)
```

(My used ranges can be seen in the picture below)
[image]

Comment: Wow! Dirk, that is a lot more elegant than what i was trying to put together! Thanks a bunch for the assistance